# PL/SQL developer doesn't export all rows

Tags: ms-access, vba, plsqldeveloper

I am querying oracle database from access vba to populate access table. The total rows returned is not same when I run the same query in PL/SQL developer and export it to CSV. Not large data just about 1000 rows. Does this have something to do with settings on PL/SQL developer?

EDIT:

The query returns different result when run through VBA.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a query it returns just the number of rows you have set, and that's what you will be exporting to CSV. So, you have to fetch all the rows whit this icons...

[image]

... and THEN export the entire results.

Here you can check the amount of records seted (it can vary according your version of PLSQL Developer), but I recommend you to leave it as default...

```
Tools -> Preferences -> Window Types -> SQL Window -> Records per Page
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the same query returns different result when run through VBA.